# htaccess url rewrite conflict

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

```
# RewriteRule ^section-([^.]+)/$ /index.php?section=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^section-([^.]+)/([^.]+)-C([^.]+)$ /index.php?section=$1&dossier=$2&catid=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Here's what i tried so far

The second RewriteRule correctly rewrites an url like that:

```
http://www.example.com/section-test/categorie-one-C001
```

But if i uncomment the first line then the second rule is broken

My problem is that i also want to rewrite this URL:

```
http://www.example.com/section-test/
```

Comment: The `[L]` means stop processing subsequent rules if matched. So when the first rule is uncommented and matched the second rule will never run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the order of the rules and also make the trailing slash optional for convenience.

```
RewriteRule ^section-([^.]+)/([^.]+)-C([^.]+)/?$ /index.php?section=$1&dossier=$2&catid=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^section-([^.]+)/?$ /index.php?section=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

*Let me know how that works out.*

Comment: You should probably remove the `L` from the flag list, as the second rule will never be processed if the first one is matched.

Comment: @imtheman No the L flag should be there that's the point of it. If the rule matches then it should stop you do not want to continue on to the next rule. Remember this is per request. So next time a page request is made and it matches the second rule it will skip the first rule and process the second. the L flags are correct.

Comment: You're right, I misunderstood what was being asked.